# stack overflow error but cant allocate on the heap

Tags: c++

I am trying to multithread a raytracer, and am trying to write a function to pass into the thread. The function throws a stack overflow error, and when I try to heap allocate, all of a sudden I can't write to the array. Any tips?

```
std::array<std::array<std::array<int,3>,400>,225> idk(std::array<std::array<std::array<int,3>,400>,225> pc,const int img_start,const camera &cam,const hittableList &world,const int imageWidth,const int img_end,const int maxDepth,const int samplesPerPixel,bool fml){
    auto pic = std::array<std::array<std::array<int,3>,400>,225> {};
    for (int i = img_start; i >= img_end; --i) {
        color pixelColour(0, 0, 0);
        for (int j = 0; j < 400; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < samplesPerPixel; k++) {

                double u = double(j + randomDouble()) / (imageWidth - 1);
                double v = double(i + randomDouble()) / (img_start - 1);
                ray r = cam.get_ray(u, v);
                pixelColour += rayColor(r, world, maxDepth);
            }
            pic[i][j] = writeColour(pixelColour, maxDepth);
        }
    }
    fml = true;
    return pic;
}

std::array<std::array<std::array<int,3>,400>,225>* idk(std::array<std::array<std::array<int,3>,400>,225> pc,const int img_start,const camera &cam,const hittableList &world,const int imageWidth,const int img_end,const int maxDepth,const int samplesPerPixel,bool fml){
    auto* pic = new std::array<std::array<std::array<int,3>,400>,225> {};
    for (int i = img_start; i >= img_end; --i) {
        color pixelColour(0, 0, 0);
        for (int j = 0; j < 400; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < samplesPerPixel; k++) {

                double u = double(j + randomDouble()) / (imageWidth - 1);
                double v = double(i + randomDouble()) / (img_start - 1);
                ray r = cam.get_ray(u, v);
                pixelColour += rayColor(r, world, maxDepth);
            }
            //this line doesnt work the = is underlined and says: no viable overloas '='
            pic[i][j] = writeColour(pixelColour, maxDepth);
        }
    }
    
    fml = true;
    return pic;
}
```

Comment: *"when I try to heap alocate all of a sudden I cant write to the array"* - you'll need to show the code where that problem happens. There isn't much of an alternative when you try to allocate so much memory that it won't fit on the stack

Comment: You may want to check `sizeof(std::array<std::array<std::array<int,3>,400>,225>)` and investigate how large stack you've got. You'll probably find that it's 1MB and that's pretty much to put on the stack. You could just make it `std::vector<std::array<std::array<int,3>,400>>(225)` and the problems would be gone. It would be _a lot_ cheaper to move that beast around too.

Comment: Start with adding `using array_3_400_225 = std::array<std::array<std::array<int,3>,400>,225>;` or something to make the code at least a bit readable...

Comment: Yes, show the code that the question is about, and explain in more detail what 'cant write to the array' means. Like do you see a compile error, a runtime error, or does the array not have the values you expected, or what?

Comment: With the way you wrote your second snippet the problem line should most likely be `(*pic)[i][j] = writeColour(pixelColour, maxDepth);` instead.

Comment: @UnholySheep that does it for that it now does compile thanks.... even though I still get the same error so I guess I'll try to use BLAS like Bathseba suggested.

Comment: @nathan That should be `(*pic)[i][j] = writeColour(pixelColour, maxDepth);`. You can't change your variable to a pointer and then just use it like it wasn't a pointer.

Comment: You are still trying to pass `std::array<std::array<std::array<int,3>,400>,225> pc` by value as a parameter, so that will obviously also lead to the same problem of overflowing the stack. So yes, looking into the alternatives suggested is a good idea

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard library requires that the payload of `std::array` has the same storage duration as the `std::array` itself.

In other words, you are attempting to place `400 * 255 * 3` `int`s on your stack, and that is above a run-time limit.

A fix is to use a multidimensional array from a third party library like Boost.MultiArray (part of [www.boost.org](http://www.boost.org)).

Comment: Only the outermost dimension should be `std::vector`, otherwise result is jagged array, not continuous block of data (which is probably desirable).

Comment: @hyde: Yes I always advise against using `std::vector<std::vector<...` for exactly that reason. Bit naughty of me then to flip. I've edited.

Comment: doesnt a run-time error mean that I have to actually run my program? because I cant even compile. 
i'll try the BLAS array though thanks.

Comment: Another fix is to simply allocate dynamically, isn't it? (Any problems that the OP has with that are likely trivial.) My gut feeling is that at least for a proof of concept learning an API is a bit overkill (you are referring to [uBLAS](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.html), right?).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: Oops - BLAS gives you a 2D array but nothing higher. I'm on slightly less shaky ground in suggesting the multiarray class from boost, even if it hasn't really been developed since 2002.